# How would I go about learning Quasi Crystal Mathematics?

Tags: geometry, crystallography

I am trying to find out a path to learn *quasicrystal mathematics*.

My math knowledge is only pretty basic however I am very much willing to work the way through up even undergrad parts and above if I can learn it through books or online.

What would it take to understand, use and work with quasicrystal mathematics.

Comment: Tip: be more specific about your maths background.

Comment: Hi, that would be like - highschool level calculus, or engineering mathematics (if that can be considered instead of building up from the highschool level)

Comment: Someone recommended the "Book of Proof" by Richard Hammack and then abstract algebra; the big book by Summit and Foote.  Good start? Where would I go from there?

Answer (score 2):

No-one will ever be puffed up with whatever sort of maths, so that any future question would become a mere execise on that basis only.

I'd advise you to have some basics on classical crystallography, lattice geometry, Voronoi / Wigner-Seitz cells, as well as Fourier transforms. Then turn towards extensions to higher dimensional geometries, cut-and-project formalisms.

There are lots of papers on that topic out there, esp. from the early time of the 1990s, or reviews on that topic since.

It more depends on which direction within the area from the maths of quasi-crystals you're interested in.